# Would this question be welcome on UX.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

We have a good but off-topic question on English.SE, and I'm wondering if UX.SE might be a better fit for it. The question asks about [how to format various currencies](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34786/international-currency-formatting-guidelines-currency-codes), which might perhaps be a good fit, as in my (very useless since I know nothing about UX) opinion, presentation of data has something to do with UX.

I'd welcome any feedback on whether or not this question would fall within the scope of UX.SE—if it'd be on-topic here, I'd love to migrate it; on the other hand, I don't want to burden you with a question that isn't right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a good question for us. Thanks :)